# Can I copy keyframes in modifier display to render?

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil

I gave an animation to Modifire. I can't see it with render.
I think it's because I only gave it to the display.
But it's hard to give keyframes to renders
Is there an easy way to transfer the keyframes on the display to the render?
[image]